# Change Redact color in Mac Preview

Tags: pdf, preview

I am running MacOS Monterey, and I want to remove some text from a PDF file using the `Redact` option in Preview. However, redacting the text marks it with black background with white crosses in it. Is it possible to change this color of redaction? Default sample redaction is shown below:
[image]